# Hidden python area debugging

Tags: python, debugging

So I created a code to respond to certain name inputs, then say something for that person. Then it will ask you what 3.55x3.55= if the correct answer of 12.6025 is inputted then it will say correct. If it is wrong, it will say Wrong I expected better of you. After this, if you type in override5555 it will rickroll you.

I tried to add another hidden area accessable by inputting "overrideKeith_".This area is a guessing game, but it won't ignore it, so it alsways opens it.
The code is

```
import webbrowser as wb
import ctypes 
import random

print("Hello, what is your first name in lowercase")
print("Hint, at the end type in override5555")
name = input()

if name == "keith":
    print("you are the awesome creator of this code")
elif name == "chad":
    print("you are great at sports")
elif name == "kurt":
    print("wow you are the fabled nerd king, just kidding you are very smart")
elif name == "nikolai":
    print("You are great at hockey and own many ferraris")
elif name == "jordan":
    print("You are very, very buff.")
elif name == "bryden":
    print("You are a great friend who always gets swishes")
elif name == "anthony":
    print("you are a very kind, and caring person.")
elif name == "kieran":
    print("you are a legendary coder")
elif name == "reuben":
    print("You wish you could code")
elif name == "paulina":
    print("You are the greatest teacher ever.")
elif name == "paulena":
    print("You are the greatest teacher ever.")
elif name == "Mrs. Sproule":
    print("You are the greatest teacher ever.")
elif name == "failure":
    print("You must be Declan")
else:
    print("Hello")

print(name)
print("do you know what 3.55x3.55=?")
answer = input()

if answer == "12.6025":
    print("correct")
else:
    print("wrong, I expected better of you.")

anything = input()

if anything == "override5555":
    wb.open('https://r.mtdv.me/pytube')
if anything == "Keith_":
    print(" override successful")
    command = input()
    if command == "command 1":
        attempts_list = []
def show_score():
    if not attempts_list:
        print('There is currently no high score, it\'s yours for the taking!')
    else:
        print(f'The current high score is {min(attempts_list)} attempts')


def start_game():
    attempts = 0
    rand_num = random.randint(1, 10)
    print('Hello traveler! Welcome to the game of guesses!')
    player_name = input('What is your name? ')
    wanna_play = input(f'Hi, {player_name}, would you like to play the guessing game? (Enter Yes/No): ')

    if wanna_play.lower() != 'yes':
        print('That\'s cool, Thanks!')
        exit()
    else:
        show_score()

    while wanna_play.lower() == 'yes':
        try:
            guess = int(input('Pick a number between 1 and 10: '))
            if guess < 1 or guess > 10:
                raise ValueError('Please guess a number within the given range')

            attempts += 1
            attempts_list.append(attempts)

            if guess == rand_num:
                print('Nice! You got it!')
                print(f'It took you {attempts} attempts')
                wanna_play = input('Would you like to play again? (Enter Yes/No): ')
                if wanna_play.lower() != 'yes':
                    print('That\'s cool, have a good one!')
                    break
                else:
                    attempts = 0
                    rand_num = random.randint(1, 10)

        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

start_game()
```

Comment: You never compare your input with the value `"overrideKeith_"`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to put start_game under the if statement (not sure that it is the exact behaviour that you want), also it is good idea to put you function definitions at the top:

```
import webbrowser as wb
import ctypes 
import random


def show_score():
    (...)

def start_game():
    (...)

print("Hello, what is your first name in lowercase")
print("Hint, at the end type in override5555")
name = input()

(...)

print(name)
print("do you know what 3.55x3.55=?")
answer = input()

(...)

anything = input()

if anything == "override5555":
    wb.open('https://r.mtdv.me/pytube')
if anything == "Keith_":
    print(" override successful")
    command = input()
    if command == "command 1":
        attempts_list = []
if anything == "override5555Keith_":
    start_game()
```